# Get the response from AsyncHttpClient and process it in the calling thread

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future, asynchttpclient

I am trying to execute http request asynchronously with async-http-client (built on top of Netty). Below is the code

```
public void fetch() {

AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = asyncHttpClient(config().setThreadFactory(new DefaultThreadFactory("thread-for-async-calls"));

BoundRequestBuilder request = asyncHttpClient.prepareGet("http://www.demo.com");

request.execute(new AsyncStateHandler())
.toCompletableFuture()
.thenCompose(res -> {
// process the response
});
 
}
```

My understanding is that when I am on thread, say "**thread-1**" and then call fetch() method, the asynchronous HTTP request will be executed on thread "**thread-for-async-calls**". Then I want to fetch the response and process the response back on the thread that called the fetch() method (in this case "**thread-1**") and not on the thread that completed the request.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

CompletableFuture's async methods allow you to provide your own Executor.

Given your example, you could

```
request.execute(new AsyncStateHandler())
.toCompletableFuture()
.thenComposeAsync(....) // Provider your own Executor here, for example your "thread-1"
```